# Should I forward arguments as *args & **kwargs?

Tags: python, optparse

I have a class that handles command line arguments in my program using python's `optparse` module. It is also inherited by several classes to create subsets of parameters. To encapsulate the option parsing mechanism I want to reveal only a function `add_option` to inheriting classes. What this function does is then call `optparse.make_option`.

Is it a good practice to simply have my `add_option` method say that it accepts the same arguments as `optparse.make_option` in the documentation, and forward the arguments as `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Should I do some parameter checking beforehand? In a way I want to avoid this to decouple that piece of code as much from a specific version of `optparse`.

Comment: "add_option ... then call optparse.make_option."  Isn't that what the normal add_option does?  If so, why override it?  Why not just ignore it?  It will be visible to subclasses.   What are you really doing?

Comment: This class will reside in a framework part that will be used be used by several applications like these. It allows retrieving parameters from several sources including the command line. Each application should subclass from it and add specific parameters. Are you saying I should just reveal the `optparse` to the subclasses instead of encapsulating it?

Comment: Why are you "encapsulating" it?  Why add complexity?  What's the benefit of this encapsulation?  What are the use cases for your new class?

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, I agree with you. The encapsulation here has no added value in this case. If I reveal the arguments of `optparse` I might as well reveal everything. On the other hand, if there was an added value to the encapsulation, it would be better to give it its own interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want your subclasses to have awareness of the command line stuff, which is often not a good idea.

You want to encapsulate the whole config input portion of your program so that you can drive it with a command line, config file, other python program, whatever.

So, I would remove any call to add_option from your subclasses.

If you want to discover what your config requirements look like at runtime, I would simply add that data to your subclasses; let each one have a member or method that can be used to figure out what kind of inputs it needs.

Then, you can have an input organizer class walk over them, pull this data out, and use it to drive a command line, config file, or what have you.

But honestly, I've never needed to do this at run time.  I usually pull all that config stuff out to it's own separate thing which answers the question "What does the user need to tell the tool?", and then the subclasses go looking in the config data structure for what they need.

Comment: A very good answer. I understand now that for encapsulating the command line parser it would be better to have it fully configurable. But I actually decided to go with S.Lott's suggestion and simply give up the encapsulation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that subclassing is what you want to do? Your overriding behavior could just be implemented in a function.